# Why aren't my Content Items accepting their new Workflow?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

All of my Content Items in one node have a bad reference to a workflow. I am trying to create one to replace the missing Workflow. I did these steps:

1. Created a new workflow
2. Located the common inherited template that all content items in this node use.
3. In the standard values I chose my new workflow for the "Workflow" and "Default Workflow" fields (I think I just need default, but I am not sure.)
4. Saved and Smart Published.

The content items still show the GUID for the missing Workflow. I click the template name at the top of the content item, double check the standard values on the template and everything looks great.

**How do I force Content Items to retrieve the correct workflow from their Templates?**

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your content items have broken from their standard values which is why your new standard value WF is not getting set. What version of Sitecore are you using? You can use the reset button on each content item to bring it back to the standard value just for the workflow.

1. Go to the **View** ribbon and enable **Standard Fields**
2. For each content item that has the wrong workflow, go to the **Versions** ribbon and click the **Reset** button on the left
3. In the pop-up scroll all the way down to the bottom **Workflow** section and check the boxes to reset specific fields
4. Repeat this process for all of the content items

Another idea is to write code to programatically reset fields or set them to a new WF

Comment: I know this is an old question but I wanted to know what is the actual purpose of the 'Reset' button. I've used it mainly to fix items that did not reflect the fields of the templates they were based on if new fields were added or the template was changed in a certain way. If I reset an item which already had values in it, would the values be overwritten by standard values?

Comment: Yes, you answered your own question. However using this Reset button on the Versions tabs lets you get to the granular field-level reset, so you can reset only individual fields back to standard values.